# What are the good formats and online platforms for my game journal?

Tags: tools, tool-recommendation

I have been thinking about creating a game journal as the GM for my upcoming role-play this winter. I will publish to the journal every 2 weeks and send the link to the players. In the game journal the players will find some handouts, summaries of what has happened, news of the world and so on. This will, I hope, help me manage more then one group of players in the same world at the same time.

I plan to publish the journal online. There are so many options for online publishing that I am at a loss of what to choose. **What are the good formats and online platforms for my game journal?**

I hope to find some good answers on the different formats and publishing platforms out there that I should consider for my publication.

---

The answere that open these questions for me is here "[How do excite my player to show up to the next session?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67453/how-do-excite-my-player-to-show-up-to-the-next-session)"

Comment: You might want to link your [previous question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67453/how-do-excite-my-player-to-show-up-to-the-next-session) as it is related to this one and give a bigger picture on what you need.

Comment: Small edits should make this a good question: you just need to narrow it down to your personal needs and not as general as it is.

Comment: Just to be clear: is this to be only *you* pushing content out to your group(s), or is there desire for multiple-authorship? (Do players also generate content?)

Comment: NO.. If players generate content then it will be edited by GM and published by GM in the journal with attribution to the player.

Comment: I think this can be answered from experience as good subjective, if you put some more detail into what you're looking for.  Everyone's solution is "good" to them, what do you mean as good, what is your use case and what do you want out of it specifically? If you want "ease of use and WYSIWYG editing" then the LaTeX answer is terrible, if you want something manual to produce professional quality layout it's good, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [vim](http://www.vim.org/), [git](http://www.git-scm.com/), and [LaTeX](http://latex-project.org/) for just that and more: character sheets and backgrounds as well as world backgrounds and in-game notes.

LaTeX is used by [writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/382/do-writers-use-latex-tex-for-writing) and [RPG geeks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/authoring-rpg-books-in-latex-what-packages-to-use) and does allow you to [create some really nice layouts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/60259#60259). [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) is a simple editor but there are [other](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) different [editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) that you can use if you do not like [vim](http://www.vim.org/).  The main advantage of [vim](http://www.vim.org/) is that it is fast and has [excellent LaTeX support](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:LaTeX). Finally, [git](http://www.git-scm.com/) is a great version control that allows you to work offline and has great merging facility so that multiple people can work on the same repository. Clearly those are all tools I use in my professional life as well thus using them in a hobby is trivially easy for me. Of course, your mileage might vary.

The other tool I have used is [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) which uses [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and [git](http://www.git-scm.com/). But I kinda assumed that if you wanted a wiki, you would not have asked the question.

Finally, [have you looked at writing (as in fiction books) software](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software?sort=votes&pagesize=50)?